# How do I add a different animation to a sprint mechanic (ROBLOX Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

`Hi, sorry first time asking a question.
Straight to the point, I've started learning Lua and how to program on ROBLOX last night, and so far I've learnt a lot of things. I'm having quite a few issues, more than what's listed in the title even. The first is that I don't fully understand how my script works.
My script is simple.
The player presses W twice in quick succession to sprint. Right now, all it does is change the players speed value. I want the animation for the character to change as well.

THIS IS THE SCRIPT IN QUESTION:

```
local Player = {
    ["Player"] = game.Players.LocalPlayer,
    ["Character"] = script.Parent,
    ["Humanoid"] = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid"),
}

local Speeds = {
    ["Normal"] = 16,
    ["Extra"] = 32,
}

local Debounces = {
    ["MaxTicks"] = 0.2,
    ["Cooldown"] = 0,
    ["Debounce"] = false,
    ["Running"] = false,
    ["LastTime"] = tick()
}
-- What do Debounces do? How do they work?
local Services = {
    ["UIS"] = game:GetService("UserInputService")
}

-- What does Connect Function do
Services.UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, isTyping)
    if isTyping then return end
    -- ^^^ Why do we put this line of code
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.W then
        if not Debounces.Debounce and not Debounces.Running then
            
            if tick() - Debounces.LastTime <= Debounces.MaxTicks then
                Debounces.Debounce = true
                Debounces.Running = true
                
                Player.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = Speeds.Extra
                
                Debounces.LastTime = tick()
                
            else
                Debounces.LastTime = tick()
                -- What are all these Debounces stuff for
            end
        end
    end
    
    
end)

Services.UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input, isTyping)
    if isTyping then return end
    
    if Debounces.Running and input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.W then
            Debounces.Running = false
            
            Player.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = Speeds.Normal
            
            wait(Debounces.Cooldown)
            Debounces.Debounce = false
            -- Same for these
    end
            
end)`
```